# Scenes not in alphabetical order anymore in Blender 4.x?

Tags: interface, scene

I have a workflow that requires many scenes, and I've been used to organizing scenes by alphabetical (and numerical) order. But now, Blender appears to be starting with alphabetical order, then moving recently edited scenes to the top. This is super weird to me, I haven't seen anything on why this is happening. Is there a way to turn this off and revert to the old way?

[image: scene order example]